# Help in bulkify trigger to camelcase fields in accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have created the following trigger with the main purpose of camel case some fields in the account object. However it seems to be breaking when I do bulk uploads (uploading business and person accounts, if it is only 1 type it doesnt break).

The fields I am looking to camel case are:

For business account: the name.

For Person Accounts: First, middle and last name

and for both the address: BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry

I thought that this code was already bulkify

Trigger:

```
trigger Account_BIBU on Account (before insert, before update) {
    Account_HDL_BIBU hdl = new Account_HDL_BIBU();

    //handleBeforeUpdate and handleBeforeInsert: update the account with camel case
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {
        hdl.handleBeforeInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
    } else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore) {
        hdl.handleBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

Class: (Edit I have updated the class)

Error Sample:

Update failed. First exception on row 2 with id 00628000002tD2FAAU; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Account_BIBU: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.SObjectException: Invalid field Name for Account

```
public with sharing class Account_HDL_BIBU {
    public void handleBeforeInsert(List<Account> newRec,List<Account> oldRec){
        updateRecords(newRec, oldRec, null); 
    }

    public void handleBeforeUpdate(List<Account> newRec,List<Account> oldRec, Map<ID, Account> oldMap){
        updateRecords(newRec, oldRec, oldMap);
    }   

    private void updateRecords(List<Account> newRec,List<Account> oldRec, Map<ID, Account> oldMap) {
        for(Account a:newRec){
            camelCase(a);
        }   
    }

    public void camelCase(Account a){
        List<String> fields = new List<String>();
        if(a.IsPersonAccount == false){
            fields = new List<String> { 'BillingStreet', 'BillingCity', 'BillingState', 'BillingCountry', 'Name' };
        }else{
            fields = new List<String> { 'BillingStreet', 'BillingCity', 'BillingState', 'BillingCountry', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName'};
        }
        String newName;
        String fnValue = '';
        List<String> nameLST = new List<String>();
        Object fieldValue;
        for(String fieldName:fields){
            if(a.get(fieldName) != null){
                fieldValue = a.get(fieldName) ;
                fnValue = String.valueOf(fieldValue);
                if(fnValue != null){
                    newName = '';
                    fnValue = fnValue.toLowerCase();
                    nameLST = fnValue.split(' ');
                    for(String s: nameLST){
                        newName = newName + s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+s.substring(1,s.length()) + ' ';
                    }
                    a.put(fieldname,newName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Query result as true but trigger result seems to be false?]

**EDIT**

It seems, it is a know issue in Salesforce, however the workaround its not working for me.

[Issue Link: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T24QAAS](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T24QAAS)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "sometimes it breaks"? Perhaps the problem is not bulkification related but is data related.

Comment: When u do a mass upload if u select update record in batches of 1, the code works fine, but if u select a greater number sometimes it breaks, i think it is when in the batch are mixed record types, i could be wrong,  however the code sometimes don't work as i specify there

Comment: Someone else may but I don't see a bulkification problem. I suggest you write some unit tests to try to find out what breaks. (And as an aside you don't have to return the Account from each method as Apex works by reference i.e. you can modify the Account that is passed into the methods.)

Comment: Thank you Keith, regarding your side note, you mean instead of having public account camelCase(Account a, String fieldName) change that to public void camelCase(Account a, String fieldName)? sorry to ask what will the main advantage on doing it this way?

Comment: i'm not sure this code handles 0 length strings in `fnValue` properly

Comment: Hi cropredy, true that is part of what i think the exception generated is, the exception is: System.SObjectException: Invalid field Name for Account . However I dont understand why feels into here becuase the only way to call method is when if(a.IsPersonAccount == false). So for instance if I am uploading or updating 10 records from dataloader, the first record is a business account, and then the rest is person, if my batch is 3 records at a time, i will have 3 failures, but i dont understand why if it shouldnt call that section if it is not a business account

Comment: The point about not returning the Account from each method is that it serves no purpose and so is misleading/adds confusion to the code. The Account is updated by `a.put(fieldname,newName);` and all the `return a;` and `a= ...` is just copying the reference to the same Account reference with `a = verifyIfNeedCamelcase(a);` ultimately updating the `a` variable to the same value it already has and then the loop it is in immediately replace that value.

Comment: Hi Keith, I have update the code, I am not sure if this is what you meant, I have also added the error that I get, i do not understand why in that record is searching for the field Name, when the field name is defined by if(a.IsPersonAccount == false), when I query the record I get the query as true: select Account.IsPersonAccount from Opportunity WHERE Id = '00628000002tD2FAAU'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment/edit, is a known issue with salesforce when using both person and business account and trying to retrieve the Name of a business account, this was my work around, I hope if someone is trying to do something similar it helps:

```
public with sharing class Account_HDL_BIBU {
    public void handleBeforeInsert(List<Account> newRec,List<Account> oldRec){
        updateRecords(newRec, oldRec, null); 
    }

    public void handleBeforeUpdate(List<Account> newRec,List<Account> oldRec, Map<ID, Account> oldMap){
        updateRecords(newRec, oldRec, oldMap);
    }   

    private void updateRecords(List<Account> newRec,List<Account> oldRec, Map<ID, Account> oldMap) {
        List<String> fields = new List<String>();
        for(Account a:newRec){
            if(a.IsPersonAccount == false){
                fields = new List<String> { 'BillingStreet', 'BillingCity', 'BillingState', 'BillingCountry' };
                a.Name = theWord(a.Name);
            }else{
                fields = new List<String> { 'BillingStreet', 'BillingCity', 'BillingState', 'BillingCountry', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName'};
            }
            camelCase(a,fields);
        }   
    }

    public void camelCase(Account a, List<String> fields){
        String newWord = '';
        for(String fieldName:fields){
            if(a.get(fieldName) != null){
                if(String.valueOf(a.get(fieldName)) != null){
                    newWord = theWord(String.valueOf(a.get(fieldName)));
                    a.put(fieldname,newWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String theWord(String fnValue){
        String newName = '';
        fnValue = fnValue.toLowerCase();
        List<String> nameLST = new List<String>();
        nameLST = fnValue.split(' ');
        for(String s: nameLST){
            newName = newName + s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+s.substring(1,s.length()) + ' ';
        }
        return newName;
    }
}
```